# Tridion Translation Manager CME extension not enabled

Tags: 2013, cme, 2013-sp1, translation-manager

I've installed Tridion Translation manager following the steps described [here](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_101E3515579A40E9B211799E2791FD7B#addHistory=true&filename=TM_Installing_installer_intro.xml&docid=concept_E6FD6FBF5ABE4713B9331A0CE77C2132&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_E6FD6FBF5ABE4713B9331A0CE77C2132&toc=false). Installation was successful, performed post-installation steps, rebooted the server, and Tridion services but still cannot get this extension to work. Also, when I select one of the "content" publications, I see the "Translation" tab initially but when I click on it, it disappears. I've enabled "verbose" logging for Translation manager but do not see anything useful in the log file.

I checked user rights (I am logged in as Administrator - publication management rights, Translation management etc are enabled)

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Translation Manager log output (After restarting the service)

Loaded configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\config\TranslationManager.xml
2014-09-09T16:10:17 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  4   Application Monitoring heartbeats initiated.
2014-09-09T16:10:17 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  4   Translation Manager Service started.
2014-09-09T16:10:17 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  Heartbeat Generator Sending Application Monitoring heartbeat on port 20131
2014-09-09T16:10:18 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  DeleteTranslationJobs   TcmClient proxy created for user "XXXX\Administrator".
2014-09-09T16:10:18 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation TcmClient proxy created for user "XXXX\Administrator".
2014-09-09T16:10:18 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  TcmClient proxy created for user "XXXXX\Administrator".
2014-09-09T16:10:18 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Dequeuing Translation Job
2014-09-09T16:10:18 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  DeleteTranslationJobs   Disposing service client
2014-09-09T16:10:18 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  SendForTranslation  Disposing service client
2014-09-09T16:10:18 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Disposing service client
2014-09-09T16:10:30 w3wp    47  TcmClient proxy created for user "XXXXX\Administrator".
2014-09-09T16:10:30 w3wp    47  Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetLoggedUser
2014-09-09T16:10:30 w3wp    47  Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetLoggedUser
2014-09-09T16:10:30 w3wp    47  Disposing service client

Comment: No, where is the license specified? TranslationManager.xml?

Comment: A valid content manager license is all that's required for translation manager. Are there any errors in the browser's console?  Anything in the event logs?

Comment: You can try using Fiddler or your browsers network monitor to see if there is an error being returned to the UI. And while please be more specific on the TM log. What is "nothing useful"? Nothing at all, or not something that is useful to you, but might be useful for others to solve the issue. I recommend stopping the TM service, delete the log, then go to the Translation tab in the UI. This will ensure the log only contains information from that single call (if any) making it easier to see if there is a problem.

Comment: I see a 500 error in firebug when I access the "Translation" tab in the publication properties window. It says "XML parsing error:syntax error location moz-nullprincipal: {} Line Number 1, Column 1. This is in the response to TranslationConfigurationManager.svc/GetDisplayTranslationsTab HTTP request with a POST parameter of tcmUri = "tcm:0-3-1". I will try restarting the TM service and post additional logs here.

Comment: I am not seeing any errors or warnings in the event viewer. I copied TranslationManager.log in my post above. Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: It appears the UI is able to call the backend service (w3wp is the IIS process, the Tridion.TranslationManager.Service lines are not relevant and I would even stop the service when debugging the UI - then only the UI logs anything). Unfortunately I do not know much about UI development, so I can't even decode the error. It appears to be client size (moz prefix). Is this a javascript error happening after it get the result, or is it the actual HTTP Respones? The HTTP Response itself is what is interesting - it could contain the error message from the server.

Comment: No, it's not a JavaScript error. The error I posted earlier was the HTTP response.

Answer (score 1):

Please ignore the previous comment regarding the "license".  The Translation Manager module does not have its own license key.  All licenses are from the CM modules.

I would suggest you open a ticket with Tridion Customer Support to investigate this.  Please provide a screenshot of what you are seeing and the Translation manager log and any event viewer messages that occurs in the same time-frame when the issue occurs (Application, Tridion and Tridion Content Manager event viewer)

Comment: Thanks for the update Brandon I didn't realise that Translation license didn't require a valid license to be installed/run.

With regards contacting support I would also suggest the opportunity to share the information is still put into here as an 'answer' once resolved - for others to benefit/learn from.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is Translation Manager module, don't forget to enable https as well (%Tridion_Home%\webui\Models\TM\web.config

Answer (score 0):

T.
The http error 500 appears to be some sort of configuration-related.
Does the TranslationManager.xml not mal-formed for some reason ? (ie...inadvertently edit it to get TMS configuration and in the process, make the .xml file mal-formed)

Answer (score 0):

If the CME is configured to use https, be sure to configure the system for use with https
For 2013sp1 system, see this SDL Live documentation:

http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?c=t&action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL+Tridion+full+documentation-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dhttps&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1411669819175&currentQuery=https&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-FA3AF8BD-D49B-42FE-A33B-44A83E42CC9C&query=&scope=&filename=GUID-FA3AF8BD-D49B-42FE-A33B-44A83E42CC9C.xml&docid=GUID-FA3AF8BD-D49B-42FE-A33B-44A83E42CC9C&inner_id=&tid=&addHistory=true&resource=&toc=false